# Advice on Layout/Structure

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, layout

I need some advice about how to approach a layout/infrastructure behind the layout.

I have put the page as it looks right now, I'm not after design advice but programmatic advice. Basically if you look where I have the 8 grey placeholders they will eventually be filled with assets for various sections of a business.

For those 8 sections they will be the disciplines for that company so like 'Retail Design', 'Masterplanning' etc... I want to create another section lower down on the page so that when they click a particular discipline it will always take them to the same section on the section lower down on the page.

However I want too display the section that they have clicked in the same div. I hope this makes sense.

I have attached an image of how it looks right now (it's just a prototype). If someone could give me some advice on this I would really appreciate it.

[Current Layout - Want to achieve the above!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UkpD.png)

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Apologies about that I didn't really know what to specify as it was quite a broad question but I just wanted some general advice about how to approach the task above. I'm more than happy too offer more information if it's needed. Kind regards.

Comment: Unfortunately, "general" advice is not really what SO is for. We are really for practical solveable programming issues.

Comment: Okay mate apologies about that. I am actually trying to solve a programmtic issue here, but I understand your concern about the information provided. If you would like to take my post down please feel free too. Just trying to get a handle on something as I have no one else to ask.

Answer (score 0):

> However I want too display the section that they have clicked in the same div. I hope this makes sense.

I'm afraid I lost you on that sentence. Please clarify and/or post a before & after image of what you are trying to achieve.

---

I'm going to assume that 'lower down' you are just trying to replace the HTML of that lower down section based on the upper section that was clicked.

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-which]')
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div.showhide')

for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
    links[i].onclick = function () {
        for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
            if(divs[i].id == this.getAttribute('data-which')) {
                divs[i].style.display = 'block'
                divs[i].scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"}) // only Firefox supports smooth scroll, others use instant scroll
            } else
                divs[i].style.display = 'none'
        }
    }
```

```css
div.showhide { display: none;/*until js shows one*/ }
```

```html
<a href="javascript:" data-which="one">link 1</a> <a href="javascript:" data-which="two"> <a href="javascript:">link 2</a> <a href="javascript:" data-which="three">link 3</a>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

lower

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
down
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
section to scroll to here:

<br/><br/>
<div id="one" class="showhide">content of 1</div>
<div id="two" class="showhide">content of 2</div>
<div id="three" class="showhide">content of 3</div>
```